# Leaflet map sends multiple geojson requests when panning and zooming - setting a timeout?

Tags: leaflet

On https://astreetnearyou.org I use the zoomend and moveend events to dynamically refresh the two geojson feeds and results pane. The problem that I am having is that they trigger too frequently, especially for example on mobile where a user might swipe the map or pinch zoom several times to get to the location they want.

Is there a way to delay requests for perhaps 300ms to catch such sequential move (drag or zoom) events?  I have seen mention of 'debounceMoveend' on https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-methods-for-modifying-map-state but I can't find any documentation on it

Comment: You probably want to [debounce](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/) your requests. Debounce implementations tend to be easy if you understand the concept and have a good grasp of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout).

Comment: @IvanSanchez thanks, I've been playing with this today, whilst balancing the  day job!  I've mainly been looking into https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function but I'm not expert enough to get it to work it seems!

I have a function `function redrawMap(hashValues) { ... } which does all the hard work and is called from various places. But the main ones are within bootleaf.map.on("dragend", function(de){ ... redrawMap(hashValues) ... }) type events

Answer (score 0):

I'm nowhere an expert on this, nevertheless I made an example:

```js
var timeout;

function onZoomEnd() {

  count = document.getElementById('counter')
  
  // CANCEL API-CALL
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  
  // API CALL
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
   count.value = parseInt(count.value) + 1
  }, 3000);
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onZoomEnd()">
 ZoomEnd!
</button>

<br>

API-calls<input id="counter" type="number" value=0>
```